# Add nodes to Drupal using API

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am building a small system which will pull products from an API and put each product into drupal db as nodes when the script is run. I am new to Drupal so I hope you will forgive any stupidness. So here is a very simple break down of what I have done so far.

1. Used php simplexml to extract products using API.

2.Stored product name description,url etc in php variables.

1. At this point I need to add them to Drupal as nodes. I got this code from web which is exactly what I require (I think )

   ```
   $node = new stdClass(); 
   $node->type = "page"; 
   $node->title = "Title";
   $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
   $node->path = array('alias' => 'your node path'); // Setting a node path
   node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.
   $node->uid = 1;
   ```

So simply putting my PHP variable in each of the above variable will do the trick. But I am stuck at where to put all this and my code? I mean do I create new php file in the drupal root or what? What files to include into it .How to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Ahmar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Ghommey said does work, however if you don't want to have to do it by creating a module and then going to a page you can use `drupal_bootstrap()` to allow you to include drupal into a .php file. [Link to Documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) Here is a code sample:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path/to/drupal');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

//add create node object here
node_save($node);
```

Comment: If you want to use filebased functions of Drupal inside that bootstrap file, dont't forget to use a chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT); first :-)

Answer (score 3):

Drupal has a module system which allows you to add your own php code.

A module requires at least two files:
a `.module` and a `.info` file.

So to create a module called `myimporter` you have to create both files relative
to your Drupal root directory:

```
sites/all/modules/custom/myimporter/myimporter.module
sites/all/modules/custom/myimporter/myimporter.info
```

The .module file will contain your php code and the .info file will contain the module
meta information.

More details about info files can be found here: http://drupal.org/node/1075072

After you created your module you have to enable it by navigating to /admin/modules .

Your module has to contain a menu declaration using the menu hook:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

So your `myimporter.module` file might look like this:

```
  <?php 

  function myimporter_menu() {
    // Register myimporter/demo
    $items['myimporter/demo'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'myimporter_demo',
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function myimporter_demo() {
    // add your node import code here
    return "Hello world";
  }
```

As you added a new menu hook element you have to clear the Drupal cache.
After that open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost/myimporter/demo`

Comment: Thanks for all the help Ghoomey. I am going for the method proposed by user above you however, I really appreciate people like you going extra mile to help others.